# Joomla Extension OrgChart

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have downloaded this extension   from  http://www.blueflyingfish.com/orgchart/index.php?option=com_orgchart&view=entitytree&Itemid=53 for organizational chart . 
My Joomla version is 1.5.26
However whenever i tried to install that extension it says NO XML setup found however it has install.xml  here is the code . or kindly suggest any other

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <extension type="component" version="1.6.0" method="upgrade">
     <name>orgchart</name>
     <creationDate>12/21/2011</creationDate>
     <author>E. Wayne Madison</author>
     <authorEmail>ewaynemadison2004@yahoo.com</authorEmail>
     <authorUrl>http://www.blueflyingfish.com/orgchart</authorUrl>
     <copyright>Copyright Info</copyright>
     <license>GNU/GPL v2</license>
     <version>1.0.2</version>
     <description>Component made by E. Wayne Madison for Joomla! 1.6/1.7 by http://www.blueflyingfish.com/orgchart</description>

 <install>
   <sql>
     <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
   </sql>
 </install>
 <uninstall>
   <sql>
     <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
   </sql>
 </uninstall>

 <installfile>install.orgchart.php</installfile>
 <uninstallfile>uninstall.orgchart.php</uninstallfile>

 <files folder="site">
    <filename>controller.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>router.php</filename>
    <filename>orgchart.php</filename>
    <folder>controllers</folder>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>helpers</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <folder>models</folder>
    <folder>views</folder>
 </files>

 <media destination="orgchart" folder="media">
    <folder>css</folder> 
    <folder>images</folder> 
    <folder>images/persons</folder>
    <folder>images/persons/cache</folder>       
    <folder>images/persons/src</folder>
    <folder>images/types</folder>
    <folder>images/types/cache</folder>
    <folder>images/types/src</folder>                       
    <folder>js</folder> 
 </media>

 <languages>
      <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_orgchart.ini</language>
 </languages>

 <administration>
      <menu task="default" img="js/ThemeOffice/component.png">orgchart</menu>
         <submenu>
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart">Control Panel</menu>
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart&amp;view=groups">Groups</menu>
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart&amp;view=positions">Positions</menu>
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart&amp;view=persons">Persons</menu>
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart&amp;view=types">Types</menu>
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart&amp;view=entities">Entities</menu>      
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart&amp;view=entity_tree">The Tree</menu>
            <menu link="option=com_orgchart&                                amp;view=entitylist">List</menu>        
         </submenu>

 <files folder="admin">
    <filename>config.xml</filename>
    <filename>controller.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>install.orgchart.php</filename>
    <filename>install.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
    <filename>install.mysql.nonutf8.sql</filename>              
    <filename>orgchart.php</filename>
    <filename>uninstall.orgchart.php</filename>
    <filename>uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
    <filename>uninstall.mysql.nonutf8.sql</filename>                
    <folder>controllers</folder>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>helpers</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
    <folder>libraries</folder>              
    <folder>models</folder>
    <folder>tables</folder>
    <folder>views</folder>
 </files>

 <languages folder="admin/language">
     <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_orgchart.menu.ini</language>
     <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_orgchart.ini</language>
 </languages>
 </administration>
 </extension>
```

Comment: XML: version="1.6.0"
YOU: My Joomla version is 1.5.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using Joomla 1.5 and the extension has been developed for Joomla 1.6.

Normally, if it was a small module, I would show you how to convert it to make it 1.5 compatible, however this is a component and is much more complex. Having checked the site where you downloaded the extension from, there is not a 1.5 version available, therefore if you really want to use it, you will need to download Joomla 2.5

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is not only organizational chart in Joomla extensions for version 1.5. Try other as well.